# Change upload options for <input type="file" accept="image/*"> in website when viewed from an android device

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, angular, responsive

It is a responsive website using *javascript*, *angularjs*.

Is it possible to change the default upload options for `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` in the website when viewed from an android device? The current options are camera, camcorder, recorder and files as the last option [image].

I would like to change it to gallery, google photos, files, or something else useful.

Or is it only possible for mobile apps?

Answer (score 1):

I think the apps available are based on the type of file you are accepting. Try adding the accept attribute.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Basically the accept attribute tells the field what type of files should be accepted here. "image/*" says that all types of images are allowed. You can also specify specific extensions. Go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) for more info

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I will edit the question to make it clearer. My bad.